# R shiny shows error in registerShinyDebugHook

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am new in R shiny package, so I tried the steps in the following website:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyrfsrd4zK0

I wrote the scripts in ui.R:

```
shinyServer(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Shiny App"),

    sidebarPanel("Side Bar"),

    mainPanel("Main panel")

    ))
```

And there is an error come out as below:

Warning: Error in registerShinyDebugHook: attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error in registerShinyDebugHook(params) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

I tried to search the solutions on web, but there is not a clear answer for this, thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't define UI within shiny server. So, remove shinyServer  from your code above and better learn shiny from official tutorials :)  http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This response is specific to the video:

At 3:30 in the video, his screen cuts for a moment and his code is changed. Below is a short version of the changes to make (originally posted in the comment section):

For ui.R file: change "shinyServer" to "shinyUI"
For server.R page: have the only code present be "shinyServer(function(input, output){})" at this point

**UPDATE:** Providing code example at JJ's request

- My recommendation is to watch this video Michal Majka referenced: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/
- I've used fluidPage for my ui

UI File

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Analysis"),

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("ABC", "ABC Range",
                  min = 0, max = 400, value = c(0,400), step = 10),
      sliderInput("DEF", "DEF Range",
                  min = 0, max = 400, value = c(0,400), step = 10),
      pickerInput("HIJ","HIJ",
                  choices = HIJ.unique,
                  options = list('actions-box' = TRUE),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      pickerInput("Year","Year",
                  choices = Year.unique,
                  options = list('actions-box' = TRUE),
                  multiple = TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myplot")
  ) 
 ) 
)
```

Server File:

```
server<- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){


  output$myplot<- renderPlot({

    filteredData <- ORIGINAL.TABLE %>%
      filter(ABC > input$ABC[1], ABC < input$ABC[2],
             DEF > input$DEF[1], DEF < input$DEF[2],
             GHI %in% input$GHI,
             YEAR %in% input$Year)

    p <- ggplot(data=filteredData,
                aes(x = filteredData$ABC, y = filteredData$DEF,
                       color = filteredData$GHI, group = filteredData$GHI, fill = filteredData$DMA)) +
      geom_point()

    p + theme(legend.position = 'none')

  })


})
```